# AutoMapper - Apply ForAllMembers instead of multiple ForMembers

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm kind of new in the world of AutoMapper, just so you know =)

I have 2 classes:

- Class LibraryParameters

```cs
public class LibraryParameters
{
     public int library_id { get; set; }
     public string document_name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public string template_name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
 }
```

- Class LibraryDocument

```cs
public class LibraryDocument
{
     public int libraryId { get; set; }
     public string documentName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public string templateName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
 }
```

So as you can see the variable names are different. So I use AutoMapper for this problem. I configured AutoMapper and made use of `.ForMember` as you can see below:

```cs
CreateMap<LibraryParameters, LibraryDocument>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.libraryId,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.library_id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.templateName,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.template_name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.documentName,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.document_name));
```

But is it not possible to avoid these different `ForMember` methods and use `ForAllMembers` for example? I can't find any information about this anywhere so you guys are my source of help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `.ForAllMembers()`, you need to specify the naming convention for the source as below:

> For `MapperConfiguration`

```cs
MapperConfiguration _config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
});
```

> For Mapping `Profile`

```cs
public class YourProfile : Profile
{
    public YourProfile()
    {
        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
    }
}
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WOUMCp)

---

**References**

[Naming Conventions | AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#naming-conventions)